# Different Namespaces for Producer and Consumer Avro Schemas

Tags: avro

Schema at producer side:

```
{
  "type":"record",
  "name":"ClientIdentifier",
  "namespace":"namespace1",
  "fields":[
    {
      "name":"data",
      "type":"string"
    }
  ]
}
```

Schema at consumer side:

```
{
  "type":"record",
  "name":"ClientIdentifier",
  "namespace":"namespace2",
  "fields":[
    {
      "name":"data",
      "type":"string"
    }
  ]
}
```

Both have different namespaces. How to make them compatible with each other.
I am using encoders and decoders present within generated avro classes for serialization and deserialization. 
Also, I am using @KafkaListener annotation in consumer in spring boot.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Were you able to resolve this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that on using the encoder within the Avro Generated Message, we can not decode back if we have a different namespace at the consumer side since it utilizes  namespace's value internally. The only option is to use GenericDatumWriter on the producer side and GenericDatumReader on the consumer side.

Comment: Hi Rohan, do you have any clue on how to use GenericDatumWriter and GenericDatumReader together? Trying it out but to no avail.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72682123/different-avro-namespaces-for-producer-and-consumer